# Moving to another activity by clicking ImageView

Tags: java, android, android-studio

I want to move to other activity by clicking photo profile, I don't know how to do it. It always give me an error when I defined it. I want to move to another activity using id in `string-array` names see **list_tutor.xml** and **strings.xml**.

```
a = (ImageView)findViewById(R.id.list_tutor);
```

If I write that code has no error, but app crashed and stop working:

```
11-30 05:57:30.787 7171-7171/com.example.abdullahalhajri.smarttutor D/AndroidRuntime: Shutting down VM
11-30 05:57:30.790 7171-7171/com.example.abdullahalhajri.smarttutor E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
  Process: com.example.abdullahalhajri.smarttutor, PID: 7171
  java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.example.abdullahalhajri.smarttutor/com.example.abdullahalhajri.smarttutor.activities.SearchRating}: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'void android.widget.ListView.setAdapter(android.widget.ListAdapter)' on a null object reference
      at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2778)
      at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2856)
      at android.app.ActivityThread.-wrap11(Unknown Source:0)
      at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1589)
      at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:106)
      at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:164)
      at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6494)
      at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
      at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:438)
      at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:807)
   Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'void android.widget.ListView.setAdapter(android.widget.ListAdapter)' on a null object reference
      at com.example.abdullahalhajri.smarttutor.activities.SearchRating.onCreate(SearchRating.java:63)
      at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:7000)
      at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:6991)
      at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1214)
      at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2731)
      at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2856) 
      at android.app.ActivityThread.-wrap11(Unknown Source:0) 
      at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1589) 
      at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:106) 
      at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:164) 
      at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6494) 
      at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 
      at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:438) 
      at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:807)
```

If I write that

```
a = (ImageView)findViewById(R.id.khalid)
```

(khalid is item on profile_pics items see strings.xml), it gives me red color error on `khalid`:

> cannot resolve symbol "khalid"

**main activity**

```
public class SearchRating extends Activity implements OnItemClickListener {
    ImageView a;
    String[] member_names;
    TypedArray profile_pics;
    String[] statues;
    String[] contactType;

    List<RowItem> rowItems;
    ListView mylistview;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.list_tutor);
        Intent intent0 = getIntent();

         a = (ImageView)findViewById(R.id.profile_pic);;
        a.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            public void onClick(View view1) {
               Intent myIntent = new Intent(SearchRating.this, TutorProfile.class);
            startActivity(myIntent);
                                 }
                             });
        rowItems = new ArrayList<RowItem>();

        member_names = getResources().getStringArray(R.array.Member_names);

        profile_pics = getResources().obtainTypedArray(R.array.profile_pics);

        statues = getResources().getStringArray(R.array.statues);

        contactType = getResources().getStringArray(R.array.contactType);

        for (int i = 0; i < member_names.length; i++) {
            RowItem item = new RowItem(member_names[i],
                    profile_pics.getResourceId(i, -1), statues[i],
                    contactType[i]);
            rowItems.add(item);
        }

        mylistview = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.list);
        CustomAdapter adapter = new CustomAdapter(this, rowItems);
        mylistview.setAdapter(adapter);

        mylistview.setOnItemClickListener(this);

    }

    @Override
    public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position,
                            long id) {

        String member_name = rowItems.get(position).getMember_name();
        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "" + member_name,
                Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }

}
```

**CustomAdapter**

```
package com.example.abdullahalhajri.smarttutor.activities;

/**
 * Created by Khalid on 11/27/17.
 */


import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Context;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.BaseAdapter;
import android.widget.ImageView;
import android.widget.TextView;
import com.example.abdullahalhajri.smarttutor.R;
import java.util.List;

public class CustomAdapter extends BaseAdapter {

    Context context;
    List<RowItem> rowItems;

    CustomAdapter(Context context, List<RowItem> rowItems) {
        this.context = context;
        this.rowItems = rowItems;
    }

    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        return rowItems.size();
    }

    @Override
    public Object getItem(int position) {
        return rowItems.get(position);
    }

    @Override
    public long getItemId(int position) {
        return rowItems.indexOf(getItem(position));
    }

    /* private view holder class */
    private class ViewHolder {
        ImageView profile_pic;
        TextView member_name;
        TextView status;
        TextView contactType;
    }

    @Override
    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {

        ViewHolder holder = null;

        LayoutInflater mInflater = (LayoutInflater) context
                .getSystemService(Activity.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
        if (convertView == null) {
            convertView = mInflater.inflate(R.layout.list_tutor, null);
            holder = new ViewHolder();

            holder.member_name = (TextView) convertView
                    .findViewById(R.id.member_name);
            holder.profile_pic = (ImageView) convertView
                    .findViewById(R.id.profile_pic);
            holder.status = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.status);
            holder.contactType = (TextView) convertView
                    .findViewById(R.id.contact_type);

            RowItem row_pos = rowItems.get(position);

            holder.profile_pic.setImageResource(row_pos.getProfile_pic_id());
            holder.member_name.setText(row_pos.getMember_name());
            holder.status.setText(row_pos.getStatus());
            holder.contactType.setText(row_pos.getContactType());

            convertView.setTag(holder);
        } else {
            holder = (ViewHolder) convertView.getTag();
        }

        return convertView;
    }

}
```

**TutorProfile**

```
package com.example.abdullahalhajri.smarttutor.activities;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v7.app.ActionBarActivity;

import com.example.abdullahalhajri.smarttutor.R;

public class TutorProfile extends ActionBarActivity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_tutorprofile);
        Intent intent0 = getIntent();
    }
}
```

---

list_tutor.xml

```
        <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:padding="2dp" >

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/profile_pic"
        android:layout_width="70dp"
        android:layout_height="70dp"
        android:contentDescription="desc"
        android:paddingLeft="10dp"
        android:paddingRight="10dp" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/member_name"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
        android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/profile_pic"
        android:paddingBottom="10dp"
        android:text="txt"
        android:textSize="20sp" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/status"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/member_name"
        android:layout_below="@+id/member_name"
        android:text="txt"
        android:textSize="16sp" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/contact_type"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignBaseline="@+id/member_name"
        android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/member_name"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:text="txt"
        android:textSize="16sp" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

**strings.xml**

```
  <!-- ListviewTuruor -->
    <string name="action_settings">Settings</string>
    <string name="hello_world">Hello world!</string>
    <!-- Names -->
    <string-array name="Member_names">

        <item>Robert</item>
        <item>Shanni</item>
        <item>Rachael</item>
        <item>Maddy</item>
        <item>Kate</item>
        <item>Emma</item>
        <item>Isabella</item>
        <item>Khalid</item>
        <item>Sophia</item>
    </string-array>

    <!-- Pictures -->
    <array name="profile_pics">
        <item>@drawable/robert</item>
        <item>@drawable/shanni</item>
        <item>@drawable/rachael</item>
        <item>@drawable/maddy_pic</item>
        <item>@drawable/kate</item>
        <item>@drawable/nikhil_pic</item>
        <item>@drawable/isabella</item>
        <item>@drawable/khalid</item>
        <item>@drawable/sophia</item>
    </array>

    <!-- Status -->
    <string-array name="statues">
        <item>Math</item>
        <item>IT</item>
        <item>Biology</item>
        <item>English</item>
        <item>Art</item>
        <item>Natural Science</item>
        <item>Art</item>
        <item>Networking</item>
        <item>Chemistry</item>
    </string-array>

    <!-- contact type -->
    <string-array name="contactType">
        <item>4.7/5</item>
        <item>4.6/5</item>
        <item>4.4/5</item>
        <item>4/5</item>
        <item>3.9/5</item>
        <item>3.5/5</item>
        <item>3.5/5</item>
        <item>2.7/5</item>
        <item>2/5</item>
    </string-array>
```

layout **activity_search_rating**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

    <ListView
        android:id="@+id/list"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        />
</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: a is being set to null in `a = (ImageView)findViewById(R.id.khalid);`. Does an image view with id **khalid** exist in layout **activity_search_rating**? Your issue is before the attempt to start the new activity.

Comment: you can see list_tutor.xml `android:id="@+id/profile_pic"` and on strings.xml   `<array name="profile_pics">       <item>@drawable/khalid</item> `

Comment: in layout **activity_search_rating** `<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

    <ListView
        android:id="@+id/list"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        />
</LinearLayout>`

Comment: your layout not contains any image view

Comment: it has imageview see list_tutor.xml

Comment: add activity tutor in manifest

Comment: `R.id.list` is not the id of your list view.

Comment: what is the id I want to get id for `<item>@drawable/khalid</item> `on `<array name="profile_pics">` on strings.xml

Answer (score 0):

The exception is telling you that in your `SearchRating.java` file, you're accessing a `ListView` that you haven't initialized yet.

Looking at your `list_tutor.xml` file, there's no ListView by that ID and that is why a NullPointerException is being the thrown in `SearchRating`'s `onCreate`.

You want to add a `ListView` with the ID `list` to your `list_tutor.xml`

*Edit*

For getting the drawables: use this method (add it in your activity)

```
public Drawable getDrawableByStringId(String strId) {
    int id = getResources().getIdentifier(strId, "drawable", getPackageName());
    return getDrawable(id);
}
```

Then add the following inside the method named : `onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id)`

```
String id = customAdapter.getItem(position).split("/")[1];
Drawable aDrawable = getDrawableByStringId(id);
```

The way you have set up your project is unnecessarily complicated. So I answered in respect to your project's setup.

Hopefully you'll learn more and realize that.

Comment: profile_pics is an array name see strings.xml want to get id for <item>@drawable/khalid</item> on <array name="profile_pics"> on strings.xml

Comment: Did you try doing what I suggested first? The problem is not in your parent Activity. The primary problem is in your `SearchRating` activity. Try fixing that first.

Comment: There is no crash it works but there is an problem if I want to click on Khalid photo it does not click I need to click on the top left corner the the screenshot  [link](https://ibb.co/nBa7pb)

Comment: can you help me which activity do I need to add these codes

Comment: Add the method in your `SearchRating`. The other two lines you'll add them to your `ListView`'s `OnItemSelectedListener` then set the drawable to your target `ImageView`

Comment: I did it but there are 3 errors  see image [link](https://ibb.co/n77ekG)  1st error getItem " non-static method cannot be referenced from a static context " 2nd error "cannot resolve symbol  listview"   3rd erorr : "cannot resolve symbol context

Comment: You should be calling `adapter.getItem` not `CustomAdapter`.  Also, remove the *context*  in return statement of the method. Also, remove *@Override* from the beginning of the same method. Another thing, instead of `listview` it should be `myListview` just like you defined it.

Comment: For now, change the line to `String id = ((String)customAdapter.getItem(position)).split("/")[1];`

Comment: I did what you said on the edited answer and there is two errors all of them in one line code which is 'String id = adapter.getItem(mylistview.getSelectedItemPosition()).split("/")[1]; '  1st error 'id' ** variable "id" is already defined on the scoop ,, 2nd 'adapter' cannot resolve symbol ,, see the image [link](https://ibb.co/dHJKkG)

Comment: Lol, this has gone from spoon-feeding to breastfeeding. Change the variable `String id` to `String strId` and then change `getDrawableByStringId(id);` to `getDrawableByStringId(strId);`

Comment: t Non-static method 'getItem(int)' cannot be referenced from a static context

Comment: That's because you changed it again. I said it should be `adapter.getItem` and not `CustomAdapter.getItem`. Please try to listen to what others tell you on here.

Comment: I am sorry but I did not change it I saw your comments 29min and I did what you tell me to do  : For now, change the line to String id = ((String)customAdapter.getItem(position)).split("/")[1]; ,

Comment: `adapter.getItem` error on `adapter`  cannot resolve symbol

Comment: Define it as a global private variable.

Comment: I did and `getItem` comes red and error and I change it to `getItem(position)` it solve and then  `split` error cannot resolve method java.lang.String

Answer (score 0):

First of you cannot defined `a = (ImageView)findViewById(R.id.khalid);` you need to define it `a = (ImageView)findViewById(R.id.list_tutor);`

Then as per your log , it shows that the values that you are passing to adapter is null. And due to this your app is getting crashed. Try to debug your app using breakpoints to check what values are getting passed when you are setAdapter

```
 mylistview = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.list);
        CustomAdapter adapter = new CustomAdapter(this, rowItems); // Here might be problem.
        mylistview.setAdapter(adapter);
```

Third thing is that define your

```
a.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            public void onClick(View view1) {
               Intent myIntent = new Intent(SearchRating.this, TutorProfile.class);
            startActivity(myIntent);
                                 }
                             });
```

in your customAdapter,