# Split method on Android using Android Studio

Tags: java, android, android-layout, android-studio

```
public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position,
                            long id) {

        String strId  = adapter.getItem(position).split("/")[1];

        Drawable aDrawable = getDrawableByStringId(strId);


        String member_name = rowItems.get(position).getMember_name();
        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "" + member_name,
                Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }

public Drawable getDrawableByStringId(String strId) {
        int id = getResources().getIdentifier(strId, "khalid", getPackageName());
        return getDrawable(id);
```

There is an error I d not know how to solve it  " split" : **cannot resolve symbol method split java lang string**

```
split("/")[1];
```

Comment: `public Object getItem(int position) {
        return rowItems.get(position);
    }`

Comment: See [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47566240/moving-to-another-activity-by-clicking-imageview/47567047?noredirect=1#comment82096974_47567047)

Answer (score 0):

If your question is how to split a string, first of all note that String.split(String) method does not exist in Android Studio. Now say

```
    s="This/ is/ demo/ string";
```

and you have to split it by "/", first you should replace all "/" by spaces as

```
    s.replaceAll("/", " ");
```

Then you should have tokenizer as

```
    ArrayList<String> sSplitted=new ArrayList<>();
    StringTokenizer stringT = new StringTokenizer(s);
    while (stringT.hasMoreTokens()) {
         sSplitted.add(stringT.nextToken());
    }
```

Hope it helps!